# #1146 - Table 'abc' doesn't exist

Tags: wamp

When i reinstall wamp (2.5), i access my table (innodb) in phpmyadmin then error message " #1146 - Table 'abc' doesn't exist.".

Log:

```
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-05 12:34:14 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-05 12:34:15 3988 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-05 12:34:15 3988 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-05 12:34:15 3988 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.17 started; log sequence number 1625987
2015-03-05 12:34:15 3988 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-05 12:34:16 3988 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-05 12:34:16 3988 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-05 12:34:16 3988 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-05 12:34:17 3988 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-03-05 12:34:17 3988 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.17'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2015-03-05 12:34:35 3988 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table ch6/ch6_users from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm  file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Comment: The message looks pretty clear.

Comment: Have you import databases/tables? Not sure, but I think databases/tables are deleted when you reinstall WAMP.

Comment: When i uninstall Wamp, data folder of mysql still in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17. When i re install wamp, phpmyadmin still show table name (frm file). But do not access it.

Answer (score 4):

INNODB databases do not exists in the `\data\ch6\???.frm` files like a MYISAM database. Those `.frm` files contains some basic scheme information, table definitions etc, but NO DATA.

The data i.e. the tables exist in the `\data\ibdata1` file, unless you made changes to the defaults.

For future reference there is a handy document on the WAMPServer forum that takes you through a fool proof way to [re-install or upgrade WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)

If you have a backup of your original install, that might be the way to go.

Unfortunately, the reinstall of WAMPServer has probably over written the `ibdata1` file and more importantly the `\data\mysql` folder, which is MySQL's knowledge of all the Databases and Tables and Users and etc etc. So you are basically using a vanilla MySQL that does not know anything about the database you think you have setup.

Comment: I think problem by i restart window when computer was crashed. then i start wamp server but it offine (organge). Then i reinstall wamp server and access those table in phpmyadmin then appearance error:  #1146 - Table 'abc' doesn't exist.".

Comment: Computer crash probably corrupted one of your databases, thats why MySQL did not start cleanly. There was no need to reinstall WAMPServer. If you are going to use INNODB database you should be familiar with how to recover them. There is a little more to it than with MYISAM databases